# Language Override entries that can work in Outlook 2016 and OWA

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

The following add-in manifest entry works in Outlook 2016 but not in OWA:

```
    <bt:String id="strAbout" DefaultValue="About">
      <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="À propos" />
      <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="Info" />
      <bt:Override Locale="de-de" Value="Über" />
      <bt:Override Locale="sv-se" Value="Om" />
      <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="バージョン情報" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-tw" Value="關於" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-cn" Value="关于" />
    </bt:String>
```

The reason why is you select just the language in Outlook 2016 and that maps to the locale entries shown in the sample above.

In OWA however you pick the language from the various regional variants. That is you do not just pick French, you pick "French (France)", "French (Canada)", etc. In that case a single fr-fr override entry will not work.

Obviously having an entry for every combination of language and culture is less than ideal.

What can you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that works is as shown in the following:

```
    <bt:String id="strAbout" DefaultValue="About">
      <bt:Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="À propos" />
      <bt:Override Locale="nl-nl" Value="Info" />
      <bt:Override Locale="de-de" Value="Über" />
      <bt:Override Locale="sv-se" Value="Om" />
      <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="バージョン情報" />
      <bt:Override Locale="fr" Value="À propos" />
      <bt:Override Locale="nl" Value="Info" />
      <bt:Override Locale="de" Value="Über" />
      <bt:Override Locale="sv" Value="Om" />
      <bt:Override Locale="ja" Value="バージョン情報" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-tw" Value="關於" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-hk" Value="關於" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-mo" Value="關於" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-cn" Value="关于" />
      <bt:Override Locale="zh-sg" Value="关于" />
    </bt:String>
```

For example in the case of French the fr-fr entry is required for Outlook 2016, and the fr entry covers all of the variants in OWA.

The case for Chinese is special. For Chinese zh alone is never sufficient as Chinese is either traditional script (zh-tw, zh-hk and zh-mo) or simplified script (zh-cn and zh-sg). In Outlook 2016 (and 2013) you select Chinese (traditional) or Chinese (simplified) which maps in that case to zh-tw and zh-cn respectively. In OWA however you select the specific Chinese variant. Therefore to have Chinese work in both Outlook 2016 and OWA you need to have an entry for each variant.

Ideally the language+script language codes would be supported so we could use zh-hant and zh-hans for Chinese (traditional) and Chinese (simplified) respectively.

**EDIT:** The suggestion for Chinese-related overrides by the Outlook Web Addins Team turned out to be a necessary improvement because of Outlook for Mac. The entries become:

```
  <bt:Override Locale="zh-tw" Value="關於" />
  <bt:Override Locale="zh-hant" Value="關於" />
  <bt:Override Locale="zh-cn" Value="关于" />
  <bt:Override Locale="zh-hans" Value="关于" />
```

- zh-tw and zh-cn: included for Desktop Outlook (Windows)
- zh-hant and zh-hans: included for OWA and Outlook for Mac

Comment: Your observation looks accurate.  Desktop Outlook and OWA are using slightly different culture fallback rules.  OWA generally follows the .Net fallback.  I think zh-hant and zh-hans should work in OWA.  This is a fairly minor point and doesn't help a lot, since you will still need zh-tw and zh-cn for Outlook 2016.